# NDAS in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04

The only thing I find is in either french or german, their website only got github and such...

Anyone know about a easy tutorial or something? Because whenever something requires compiling and the like, I can never it to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://power2build.wordpress.com/2013/02/02/ubuntu-in-action-ndas/
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2150780

with kind regards,
~remke
The Netherlands

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I won't be trying it out any time soon, since I went around the problem (with servers), but thanks for the answer! Great detail in the wordpress page, seems easy even for me! :D